# My a href tag on image doesn't work when the site is resized to a smaller width

Tags: html, css, image, href

Here is the site: http://boceski.16mb.com/
I have images from flags in the top left angle of the page.
When I click the image, it changes the text to other language.
The images are clickable and I can change the language when I view them on my normal screen, but when I resize the website or when I open the website from mobile, I can't change the language. It doesn't read the `<a href="">` tag. 
I don't know why, Can you please help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `z-index: 2` into de CSS to the `.header` rule.

*Recomendation: Make flags images bigger to get a better user experience in mobile context.*

Answer (score 0):

Here is the screenshot from 320 x 480 px resolution, like standart phone. And your flags are here, everything is OK.

[image]

And yes, make them a little bigger, as @anfuca said, it will be more comfortable to use